# How to call function without onload

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out a way to dynamically write to a table in the body from the head and came across this sample code. The problem is that it calls the function using 'onload'. I need to call the function from a loop in my code to write to the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
.mytable {
border:1px solid #000000;
border-collapse:collapse;
width:200px;
}
.mytable td{
background:#cccccc;
border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
var nrCols=2;
var maxRows=4;
var nrRows=maxRows+1;
while(nrRows>maxRows){
nrRows=Number(prompt('How many rows? Maximum '+maxRows+' allowed.',''));
}
var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
var tab=document.createElement('table');
tab.className="mytable";
var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
var row, cell;
for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
    row=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
        cell=document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+' '+j))
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbo.appendChild(row);
}
tab.appendChild(tbo);
root.appendChild(tab);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to name the function and get rid of the onload and call the function from the script in the head but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to put the `script` **after** the div in the html to use `function foobar()` and afterward write `foobar();`

this is for calling a function, however `onload=function()` can also works in the `<head>` tag. the reason is if its a function the page renders in order and the `<div>` will not exist at the point the page reaches it if its in the head, however `onload` means **after** the page has finished loading.

Comment: No the code that I pasted works fine, but I need to modify it to fit my requirements. The reason I used that sample is because the script is in the head, which is part of my requirement.

Comment: If I put the script after the div in the html how can I call the function from the head?

Comment: Ok, that's the problem I'm having. I need to call the function from inside a loop inside code in the head so I can't use onload=function().

Comment: I meant that your solution is very problem I'm having, unless I'm not understanding you.

1) I can't put the script after the div in the body, because then I can't call the function from the head
2) I can't use the onload function in the head because it will just run by itself. I need to call the function from within a loop several different times during runtime.

Comment: @user2721465 well then name the function like so: `function foo()` and call it in your program like so: `foo();` unless im missing something...

Comment: @user2721465 well you fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tx5Xd/ is exactly what i described i guess i just dont get your question

Comment: @user2721465 if i get your question properly you want to use a function call and not onload in the head sorry not possible you also cant run a program without a browser or type without a computer.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible. I worked out that I just need to remove the head and body tags. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that difficult. But first you must segregate the js and mark up.

Segregation allows you better code management . Try this :

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

**JS:**

```
writeToTable();
function writeToTable(){
var nrCols=2;
var maxRows=4;
var nrRows=maxRows+1;
while(nrRows>maxRows){
nrRows=Number(prompt('How many rows? Maximum '+maxRows+' allowed.',''));
}
var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
var tab=document.createElement('table');
tab.className="mytable";
var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
var row, cell;
for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
    row=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
        cell=document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+' '+j))
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tbo.appendChild(row);
}
tab.appendChild(tbo);
root.appendChild(tab);
}
```

Find the working solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/tx5Xd/

Comment: I've coded my java application already except the output to a table part. What would I have to actually do to segregate my code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the question but define your function the the header and then call your function at the end of your html file.

Comment: I have to call the function from the header.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of handling situations like this is to a) still use `onload`, because it's a great way for the browser to inform you that the content has finished loading; but b) go ahead and factor your code into its own function, but then just call *that function* from your `onload` handler. For example:

```
function myFunction(param1, param2) {
    // do your important stuff here
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    myFunction('foo', 'bar');
}, false);
```

That way, your function still won't get called until after the page finishes loading, but you can also call it separately later if you like.

Comment: Looks promising, but I'm having trouble passing a string as an argument to the function which would be required in my application.

Comment: And I still can't call the function in a particular place/time in the code.

Comment: You can wrap an anonymous function around your `onload` function, which will let you pass parameters in when it gets called (updated the code above to show). And you absolutely can call the function `myFunction` whenever you like, there's nothing stopping you.